# Exec Stored Procedure on particular day of week

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a procedure which should execute on specific day i.e. only on Monday of the week.

How to call it from another procedure passing variable or parametre ? 
without using SQL server agent

```
declare @wday as nvarchar
set @wday = (select DATENAME(dw,getdate()))

select @wday as day1
```

Comment: You could schedule a job for every Monday of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've specified you don't want to use SQL Server Agent for this, it becomes a fairly simple if statement:

```
DECLARE @wday NVARCHAR(10)
SET @wday = (SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()))
IF @wday = 'Monday'
BEGIN
  -- Execute your procedure here
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably create an Agent Job

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Well, that serves the purpose but i want to do it at code level.

Comment: You need *something* to schedule the execution of the SPROC. The agent job is that scheduler. How are you planning to schedule it in code? You have to write the SQL to execute the SPROC. (EXECUTE SP_NAMEHERE)